# Custom property file in spring boot for different environments (prod/dev)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I want to keep a custom property file name(modulexx-config.properties) & not application.properties in my application. How to specify the configuration differently for the various environments ?

Answer (score 0):

just provide your custom name via the `spring.config.name` property

let's say you want to use `modulexx-config-dev.properties` and `modulexx-config-prd.properties`

then if you start your application via

`java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.name=modulexx-config --spring.profiles.active= dev`

then `modulexx-config-dev.properties` will be used